# Are irregular surfaces of equal electric field magnitude special?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, symmetry, gauss-law

When we use Gauss' law to derive expressions for the electric field, we usually exploit certain symmetries to ensure that the $E$ term is constant and pulls out of the electric flux integral. For example, to calculate the electric field due to a point charge, we can use a spherical surface focused at the center, because the magnitude of the electric field is uniform everywhere along the surface.

I noticed that it is actually not strictly the coordinate symmetry but the uniformity of the electric field magnitude along a surface that determines whether a configuration can be simplified in this manner (if we want to be really precise). One could imagine (for example) a surface around a triplet of charges, that has a closed form formula and a nicely integrable surface area, with constant electric field magnitude, enabling us to simplify Gauss' law, but is nevertheless effectively asymmetric (one would first, however, need to find a formula defining surfaces of this kind, although it seems sufficiently feasible). So, what prevents us from finding a surface with this type of uniformity for any system of charges? It seems like there should be a concise theory for developing surfaces of uniform electric field magnitudes around arbitrary configurations of charges, that could lead to the simplification of Gauss' law in any scenario imaginable. Or at least an alternate way of getting to the answer. Is there any literature on these kind of surfaces of uniform electric field magnitude? Is that concept of any significance whatsoever?

Comment: If you want to try an example, my suggestion for the next best thing after a point charge would be a dipole. ;)

Comment: @kricheli sure, that's interesting, but not exactly what my question is about

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, just a clarification of a wrong assumption/an omission in your reasoning.

When you calculate the electric field of a spherically symmetric charge distribution using Gauß' law, you first use the given charge and Gauß' law to determine the integral of, and thus the average of, not just the field magnitude on the surface you are integrating over, but the *dot product of the field and the surface normal vector*. You then use the symmetry to deduct that not just the field magnitude, but said dot product is constant on the surface, and therefore obtain the value of the dot product, and further the electric field.

So I doubt the approach you are thinking of would be that useful...

Comment: That's a good point. Yeah, what I meant is the magnitude of the electric field projected on the surface normals, not just the magnitude of the electric field on the surface. The question still remains though

Comment: This does change the question a bit: In a given electric field $|\vec{E}|=const \neq 0$ implicitly defines a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ through the implicit function theorem (a non-vanishing differential assumed), while constructing a surface out of $\vec{E}\cdot \vec{n} = const$ is not as straightforward, as far as I'm aware.